# Sync link for syncing shared OneDrive folder doesn't install

Tags: windows, windows-10, office365, onedrive, sharepoint

We have an Office 365 Business account.

I have set up a shared SharePoint/OneDrive folder, it can be accessed online from O365>OneDrive>Shared Libraries

When I press the Sync link above the Documents I get the prompt "This link need to open in: Microsoft Onedrive" and I approve. Then nothing happens.

I installed the latest OneDrive client:

```
Version 2020 (19.232.1124.0012)
```

What can be done to make the sync work?

Answer (score 0):

Reason why nothing happened is that even if OneDrive account was active and logged in it was only the Personal account with the same e-mail address. When actively logged in again with the same username and selecting business account then Sync also worked.